# Find the first empty row after the given row number in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I need to **find** the **first empty row number** after the given row number.

please check the image below

[image: Please check the image]

for e.g: assume, my current row number is 6 then my output should be 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use CountA to see if the entire row is empty.

```
   Function FirstEmtpyRow(startRow As Long) As Long

        Do
            startRow = startRow + 1
            If startRow = rpws.Count Then Exit Function

        Loop Until WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rows(startRow)) = 0

        FirstEmtpyRow = startRow

    End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim startRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim sh As Worksheet


startRow = 2  'Set first row to check
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

lastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = startRow To lastRow
    If sh.Cells(i, 1) = "" Then
        MsgBox "First empty row: " & i
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
```

Have you tried something like this?

**Note:** This won't show you when the last row is empty.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
function FindFirstEmpty(i as long)

while cells(i,1).value <> ""
    i = i + 1
wend

FindFirstEmpty = i

End function
```

Depends how you are obtaining the row from which to begin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .End(xlDown) but you have to be careful that the immediately next cell is not blank or you could skip over it.

```
dim rw as long, nrw as long
rw = 6
with worksheets("sheet1")
    with .cells(rw, "A")
        if IsEmpty(.Offset(1, 0)) then
            nrw = rw + 1
        else
            nrw = .end(xldown).offset(1, 0).row
        end if
    end with
end with

debug.print nrw
```