# Copy and Paste in next empty row beginning with B59

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I used this line in VBA before to paste data on the first empty row in a worksheet

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
```

Is it possible to modify it, so it pastes the data on the first empty row beginning with B59?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38387893/find-the-first-empty-row-after-the-given-row-number-in-excel-vba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That line of code is looking for the last row with content in column B and pasting below that.

If Column B has no text you could add any content on cell B58 and your line of code will start pasting into B59,

If column B already has text below B59 and you want to overwrite it you should add a loop or For do something like this:

```
    For x = 59 To 100
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
    Next
```

Answer (score 1):

The `End` method returns the first non-empty cell of the entire row or column that the range is in, so for example the obvious:

```
Range("B59:B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
```

doesn't stop at `B59`.

This does however mean that

```
Range("B58").End(xlUp)
```

will return a different range if there is nothing beyond cell `B58`, and will return the same range otherwise.

Try

```
If Range("B59:B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp) <> Range("B58").End(xlUp) Then
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
Else
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B59").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
EndIf
```